# Print function failing because of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

When I comment out the for loop everything works. However, as soon as it is active again IDLE spits out a syntax error. I've tried spacing it appropriately, as that was one of the suggests on other questions, but that hasn't worked regardless of the amount of times I hit enter.

```
# futval.py
# A program to compute the value of an investment
# carried 10 years into the future

#begins main function of program

def main():

    #description of program 

    print("This program calculates the future value")
    print("of a 10-year investment.")

    #creates and assign three variables to user input

    principal = eval(input("Enter the initial principal: "))
    apr = eval(input("Enter the annual interest rate: "))
    compound = eval(input("How often is the interest compounded: "))

    #begins a 'for' loop that iterates 10 times indicative of 10 years

    for i in range(10):
        print (principal)
        principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound)

    #prints out the final result of the above equation. 
    print("The value in 10 years is:",principal)

    #original program exited too fast and didn't allow user to see output
    #I added the following line so the user could see.

    print(input("Press enter to exit."))

main()
```

Comment: You need another parentheses after `principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound)
`

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is that you are missing one closing parenthesis:
Change `principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound)`
To `principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound))`

Also, you should get out of the habit of using `eval` since it's usually considered dangerous and definitely not needed here. Just casting to a type and catching exceptions is fine here.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are sections of this code that are for a college assignment. That happens to be one of the portions that the professor gave us, so I can't mess with it. 

I'll heed your advice on my own projects though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you have omitted a `)` after `(apr/compound)`

```
for i in range(10):
        print (principal)
        principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a missing bracket. Otherwise it works fine.

your code :

```
principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound)
```

it should be : `

```
principal = principal * (1 + (apr/compound))`
```